# Scan the barcode in Google glass using Android Studio

Tags: android, zxing, google-glass

I am using Android Studio as an IDE to develop the Google Glass Application.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
```

But it gives the error saying cannot resolve symbol 'android'.

I have added the Gradle dependency as below:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.3.0'
```

Because of this, I cannot run the project. Please let me know what can be done to resolve the issue. Also if any other or better alternative is available, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just including the ZXing core you won't have any of the Android code for ZXing.

Take a look at BarcodeEye: https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye

Comment: How to use this library because there is no documentation of it. I mean which classes to use and what are the available APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `core` won't do anything if you are integrating by `Intent`. You need `android-integration`, if anything, to use `IntentIntegrator`. Starting the `Intent` as you show won't quite work. Also, you should use a much newer version -- 3.1.0, not 2.3.0. Finally you need to build and install the Glass app, which is in the project at `glass/`. I have not tested it with `Intent`s but someone mentioned it works?

Comment: I have tried IntentIntegrator but it asks to download Zxing barcode reader, which I do not want. As user cannot download it in Glass.

Comment: Right, you would have to have the app installed already. You can reuse the code in `glass/` in your app according to the open source license. It's quite minimal right now though.

Answer (score 0):

For scanning bar codes I'm using zbar libraries. I have downloaded and added the `zbar.jar` into the libs folder of my Android Studio Project and then added to the gradle dependencies like:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
}
```